# jQuery elements in a loop

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

I have a loop in Java style, which out on home page a list with text and checkboxes. So I have a set of checkboxes.
I have to show message when I click to ANY checkbox, but in my variant message showes only when I click the first checkbox.

My checkbox in loop

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.flights}" var="flight">
    <input type="checkbox" class="deleteBox"/>
 </c:forEach>
```

My script

```
$(".deleteBox").change(function(){
        $("#deletePanel").each(function(index, element){
            if($(".deleteBox").prop("checked")){
                console.log("true");
                $("#deletePanel").css("display","inline");
            }else{
                $("#deletePanel").css("display","none");
                console.log("false");
            }
        });
    });
```

Message div

```
<div id="deletePanel" style="display: none">Delete selected</div>
```

Comment: `$("#deletePanel").each(` Can we iterate over a single element? Show the rendered HTML. That would be helpful to answer your question

Comment: and also make sure you don't have elements more than one if you are using id `deletePanel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(".deleteBox").change(function(){
    // use $(this) to check state of current changed checkbox
    if($(this).prop("checked")){
      console.log("true");
      $("#deletePanel").css("display","inline");
    }else{
      $("#deletePanel").css("display","none");
      console.log("false");
    }
});
```

As you only have one `#deletePanel`, you don't need the each function - just check if the delete checkbox is checked on change and show the message if it is

**Update**

As per comment I would do it like this:

```js
$(".deleteBox").change(function(){
  if($(".deleteBox:checked").length){
    console.log("true");
    $("#deletePanel").css("display","inline");
  }else{
    $("#deletePanel").css("display","none");
    console.log("false");
  }
});
```

Comment: there is one problem: when you have few checked and you unchecked one message doesn't show.

Comment: See edit above, it should check how many checkboxes are checked and then show / hide message

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `.toggle()`:

```
$(".deleteBox").change(function(){
    $("#deletePanel").toggle(this.checked); 
});
```

Comment: toggle will set display properties `block` and `none`. not `inline` and `none`

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy that's true. But i am not sure if OP knows it that div is block level element.